# How do I read the number of characters from a input in C?

Tags: arrays, c, input, char, character

I am trying to read the number of characters including, the spaces.
I use the scanf function to check for chars using %c. Also on a side note, how would I go about storing the input into an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char n, count= 0;

  while (scanf("%c", &n) != EOF) {
    count = count+1;
  }  

  printf("%d characters in your input \n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

When I test input (with spaces) such as
abcdefg
it doesn't print anything.

Comment: `scanf` is unnecesarily heavy for this task, `n=getc(stdin)` is enough. Well, you can store them by writing them to a long enough array.

Comment: @Fread, How do you end you input, with a line-feed, end-of-file signal or what?

Comment: Try adding `printf("%d\n", n);` in the loop for more info.

Comment: I end the input with Ctrl-D. Adding printf("%c\n", n); printed each char (I changed the format specifier to c)
When I inputted apple it printed
apple, each char on its own line

Comment: It works here https://ideone.com/9wnvFc

Comment: On some Linux shells Ctrl-D sends an EOF only at the beginning of a new line, so run your original program, write on the console "abcd" then hit the Enter key then hit Ctrl-D. Anything changes?

Comment: Another comment on your question: "storing the input into an array". In C there's no type called simply "array". Try to always be clear on which type you're talking about. You can have an "array of N elements of type T". So which type do you want an array of 100 char? Of 1000 char? This calls for the concept of dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You will need to press `Ctrl+d` twice. Once to indicate you are done taking input (where the last character is returned and then `scanf()` blocks waiting on the next character) and then returns `EOF` on the next `Ctrl+d` keypress because there are no characters read before end of input is generated.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a MAX_CHAR and checking that in loop would protect you against invalid memory write.
Remember that last byte of an array should be left for '\0', if you want to print or use the char array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_CHAR 100

int main(void) {

char n[MAX_CHAR]={0}, count= 0;

while((count!=MAX_CHAR-1)&&(scanf("%c",&n[count])==1))
{
    if((n[count]=='\n')){
        n[count]=0;
        break;
    }
    count++;
}

printf("%d characters in your input [%s]\n", count, n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: UV for a good answer employing checks.  Note: `while(scanf("%c",&n[count]))` should be `while(scanf("%c",&n[count]) == 1)` to avoid  looping on EOF.  Consider though performing the `count==MAX_CHAR-1` before reading data else input byte is lost.

Comment: Thanks for recommending the EOF check

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` does return EOF when it reaches the end of the file. But in order for you to see that happening, you should give your program a file input when you call it like this:

```
./a.out < input.txt
```

Inside `input.txt` you could put any text you want. But if you want to work in the command line, you should read until you find a `\n`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char n, count = 0;
  scanf("%c", &n);
  while (n != '\n') {
    count = count+1;
    scanf("%c", &n);
  }  

  printf("%d characters in your input \n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

If you want to store the input in an array, you must know the size of the input (or at least the maximum size possible)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char n, count = 0;
  char input[100]; //the max input size, in this case, is 100
  scanf("%c", &n);
  while (n != '\n') {
    scanf("%c", &n);
    input[count] = n; //using count as the index before incrementing
    count = count+1;
  }  

  printf("%d characters in your input \n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, if don't know the size or max size of the input, you'd have to dynamically change the size of the `input` array. But I think that would be a little advanced for you right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you asked for, but I was searching for a program where a user is entering a string and when he/she press enter after completing his string, the program stops and tell the number of character in that string he/she entered. This one worked for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
char n, count= 0;

while (scanf("%c", &n) && n != '\n') 
{
count = count+1;
}  

printf("%d characters in your input \n", count);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `printf` doesn't print anything because runtime doesn't reach to it. Your code looping for ever in `while` loop

```
  while (scanf("%c", &n) != EOF) {
    count = count+1;
  }
```

because `scanf` won't return `EOF` in this case

Comment: On end-of-file I'd expect `scanf()` to return `EOF`.  Are you sure about  "scanf won't return EOF in this case"?

Comment: The loop is fine. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf you can read that scanf() returns "EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned."